# Internet Explorer Tab title too small

Tags: fonts, size

I ajusted the system font size on Windows 7 by mistake. Through some operations, I resumed the font size, except the font size for Internet Explorer Tab titles, which is shown by the figure posted. How can I make that font size larger?

[image: Internet Explorer Tab font size too small]

Comment: Internet Explorer 8

    Click Page at the top of the browser window, and then click Text Size.

    Choose the text size that you want.

Internet Explorer 9

    Make sure you can see the command bar. If you can’t see it, place your mouse pointer in the blank area to the right of the tabs, right-click, and then choose Command bar.

    On the command bar, click Page, and then click Text Size.

    Choose the text size that you want.

Comment: thanks, I revert to the default settings by running a registery file.